# Javascript regex to match a string that ends with some characters but not with a particular combination of those

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say using Javascript, I want to match a string that ends with `[abcde]*` but not with `abc`.

So the regex should match `xxxa`, `xxxbc`, `xxxabd` but not `xxxabc`.

I am utterly confused.

**Edit:** I have to use regex for some reason, i cannot do something `if (str.endsWith("abc"))`

Comment: Should `[abcde]*` really be `[abcde]+`? Otherwise `xxx` matches just fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is simple: use negative lookahead:

```
(?!.*abc$)
```

This asserts that the string doesn't end with `abc`.

You mentioned that you also need the string to end with `[abcde]*`, but the `*` means that it's optional, so `xxx` matches. I assume you really want `[abcde]+`, which also simply means that it needs to end with `[abcde]`. In that case, the assertions are:

```
(?=.*[abcde]$)(?!.*abc$)
```

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for tutorials on positive and negative lookarounds.

---

I was reluctant to give the actual Javascript regex since I'm not familiar with the language (though I was confident that the assertions, if supported, would work -- according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), Javascript supports positive and negative lookahead). Thanks to Pointy and Alan Moore's comments, I *think* the proper Javascript regex is this:

```
var regex = /^(?!.*abc$).*[abcde]$/;
```

Note that this version (with credit to Alan Moore) no longer needs the positive lookahead. It simply matches `.*[abcde]$`, but first asserting `^(?!.*abc$)`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Try it in Javascript - the second regex matches "xxabc".

Comment: @Pointy: `"xxabc".matches("(?=.*[abcde]$)(?!.*abc$).*")` is `false` in Java; I admit that I'm not familiar with any particular Javascript flavor, but if it supports positive and negative lookahead, then the regex should work.

Comment: @Pointy: `"xxabc".match(/^(?=.*[abcde]$)(?!.*abc$).*$/)` is `null` in Javascript (though I'm not sure if this is the proper way to regex in this language).

Comment: Try regex.test("xxabc") - returns boolean

Comment: I think it works in the form you give in that comment, with the "$" at the end of the pattern outside the groups.

Comment: I don't think the *positive* lookahead is necessary: `^(?!.*abc$).*[abcde]$`

Comment: @Alan: yep, you're right =) Suggestion incorporated with full credit.

Answer (score 16):

Either the question is not properly defined, or everyone is overlooking a simple answer.

```
var re = /abc$/;

!re.test("xxxa");    // pass
!re.test("xxxbc");   // pass
!re.test("xxxabd");  // pass
!re.test("xxxabc");  // fail
```

All of these end in `/[abcde]*`/

Comment: Simple, clever. Just do also test for last char and 'and' boolean results.

Comment: Agree, very simple, but for my [use case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555116/1008999) it would not have work with the `!` in the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note *every* string ends with `[abcde]*`, as that allows zero width. Thus we're really just looking for a regex that matches strings that don't end in `abc`. Easy.

```
([^c]|[^b]c|[^a]bc)$
```

That's something that's not `c`, something that's not `b` followed by `c`, or something that's not `a` followed by `bc`, and whichever option of those, then followed by the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to say to @maček that you answer is simple and clear with `!` in the beginning
But I really wanted the not operator to be inside the regexp so i could use it with eg: `Array::some`, `Array::filter`, `Array::find`, `Array::findIndex` and without having to create a function or a wile loop

Here is an example:

```js
var items = ["ja", "ka", "mf", "bg", "vb", "b"]
var regex = /^((?!a$|b$).)*$/; // match a string that doesn't end with a or b

var matched = items.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, regex);

alert(matched); // result: ["mf", "bg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ...

```
var regex = /(ab[abde]|[abcde])$/; // wrong
```

maybe? wait no; hold on:

```
var regex = /(ab[abde]|([^a].|.[^b])[abcde]|\b.?[abcde])$/;
```

So that's "ab" followed by "a", "b", "d", or "e"; or any two-character sequence where the first character isn't "a" or the second character isn't "b", followed by "a" through "e"; or any word boundary followed by any character (possibly) followed by "a" through "e". The last clause is to deal with short strings; it's sort-of cheating but in this case it works.